# Open Gmail Client With File Already Attached

Tags: gmail-api

I see you can send emails with uploaded attachments using the Google Gmail API.  However, I want the user to be able to preview the email before sending.  It looks like there isn't a way to do this?

So essentially would the only solution be to create my own simple email client, then send the email through the API?  Or would using the API even be necessary as in that case I could just use the server's native sendmail client to sent out the email with the user's gmail address as the return address.

I guess using the API, the advantage is the email would appear in the user's SENT folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a live preview that's available in a way you intended. As far as I know, Outlook (for reference) doesn't even have it. What they have is to upload the attachments while the mail is still being drafted.

The best I can think of is once the message will be sent, [save it as draft](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) at first and [retrieve the mail again](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/get) on the succeeding page. This will look like a preview that you intended. Once done, you can then finally [send the drafted email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) to the receipients.